# text_field_tag placeholder ignoring dynamic text after space in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n

I am using I18n for internationalization. for displaying place holder content in locale language in placeholder of text_field_tag im using following code.

```
<%= text_field_tag('email', "", class: 'form-control', placeholder: t('shared.enter_email')%>
```

And `config/locales/en.yml` content is as follows:

```
en:
  shared:
    enter_email: Enter Email
```

on running application, the content in the placeholder contains only `Enter` and its ignoring `name` because there is a space in-between.

i tried different syntax, all are producing same result. Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: yml should be like this probably `enter_email: 'Enter Email'`

Comment: did you restart your server after that?

Comment: inspect input tag. what `placeholder` attribute contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using interpolation like this.

```
<%= text_field_tag('email', "", class: 'form-control', placeholder: "#{t('shared.enter_email')}" %>
```